# text-binding with an inline function

Tags: knockout.js

can I do something like this with a `text-binding` ?:

```
<span data-bind="text: function(item) { return item+' something'; }">item something</span>
```

At the moment I get something like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: function(item) { return item; }">function(item){ return item;}</span>
```

I know for `optionsText` this would work.

What to do here ?

Comment: In the documentation (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) says that "...If you supply something other than a number or a string (e.g., you pass an object or an array), the displayed text will be equivalent to yourParameter.toString()".  You could use a computed observable instead.

Comment: Just set an `item` as observable and try this out:
`<span data-bind="text: item()+' something'">item something</span>`
As far as I remember it will build computed under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not bind a function to the `text` binding, but there are a few routes you could take to accomplish your goal:

- creating a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) in your viewModel
- unwrapping the observable in your binding
- using [knockout.punches](https://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/)

#### Explicit computed

```
this.item = ko.observable()
this.transformedItem = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return this.item() + ' something'
})
```

#### Unwrapping observable in HTML

```
<span data-bind="text: item() + ' something'"></span>
```

#### [knockout.punches](https://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/)

```
<span>{{item}} something</span>
```